# How to test for non-2-digit file names with batch

Tags: batch-file

I need to find out if all jpg files in a directory have 2-digit names (01, 02, 30, 99 e.g.). If they don't, they need to be renamed. If they do, they've already been renamed and I shouldn't change them.

The test code below lists each file name with "yes" if the name is two digits or "no" if it isn't. **The problem is it consistently returns "no" for files 08.jpg and 09.jpg.** I've tested it on several directories.

```
@Echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

For %%G in (*.jpg) do (
    Set "filename=%%~nG"
    Set found=no
        For /L %%H in (1,1,99) do (
            If !filename! EQU %%H set "found=yes"
        )
    echo !filename! !found!
)
```

I use the same rename bat on all dirs and thought it might be renaming 08 and 09 in some weird way, but 01 through 07 are fine and manually renaming 08 and 09 doesn't help. Could it be something in the way For /L increments? What else should I look for?

BTW, it's okay if there are "gaps" between the numbered names--01, 03, 10, 11 is fine--so I don't need to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
dir /b *.jpg| findstr /v /i /r /b /e "[0-9][0-9].jpg"
```

should be faster to filter files with `FINDSTR` instead of iterate with `FOR /L` .

Comment: The dir solution would be fine, but I am not sure how to "turn around" either of these to list files that **do not** match the 2-digit format--or just find out if any files do not match so I know I must rename. Thx

Comment: Changed question to "non-2-digit" It was probably misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code fails is because `IF` treats 0 prefixed numbers as octal, and `08` and `09` are not valid octal numbers. So `IF` then does a string comparison instead of a numeric comparison, and `08` does not equal `8`.